# Highcharts - Alignment issue on 3rd Y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have three Y axis and two of which has got multiple spline series to be shown. My data is a time series data and it is all working as expected. Just that the labels of one of the Y axis is mixing up with chart area.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ismusidhu/yaxis_alignment_issue_highcharts/tree/master/

[image: Chart image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve it by setting appropriate `yAxis.offset`:

```
yAxis: [{
  title: {
    text: "POAI [W/m2]"
  },
  opposite: true,
  offset: 70,
  min: 0,
  labels: {
    format: "{value} W/m2"
  }
}]
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/alignment-of-highcharts-tertiary-y-axis-issue-bo7h4